# Filtering SQL table to display totals based on an "invoice_status"

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Background: I am developing some stored procedures for a project and want to display a sum total of earnings based on specific criteria dictated by a column I created called "invoice_status"--this column has the datatype ENUM and only allows for names like "Delivered", "Processing", and "Shipping"

I am looking to create a procedure that displays the total earnings on invoices that are listed as "Delivered".  Here's my sql so far:

```
 select invoice_id, total_cost, invoice_status from invoice
 union
 select count(invoice_id), sum(total_cost), null
 from invoice;
```

I tried filtering the results using "where invoice_status = "Delivered"", but this doesn't affect the sum and count values

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the condition on both queries

```
 select invoice_id, total_cost, invoice_status from invoice
 where invoice_status = "Delivered"
 union
 select count(invoice_id), sum(total_cost), null
 from invoice
 where invoice_status = "Delivered";
```

Comment: This works, thank you!
So just a quick question to make sure I understand this correctly: since I am using "SELECT" twice, it counts as two queries and therefore both need to use the "WHERE" clause for it to be effective?

Comment: exactly! You can consider __union__ as a glue between 2 queries.